# How can I add textarea dynamically to jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog

I need to add the textarea to the dialog. Please suggest me if any ideas.
Here is my code...

```
var story = changeStory();  
   $.ajax({  
        async: false,  
        type:"GET",  
    data:{"story":story},  
    url: "./teststory.action",  
    dataType: 'json',  
    success: function(json){  
    var i = 0;
    var jsonList = "";  
      $.each(json, function(index,job) {    
        if(i > 0){  
            jsonList = jsonList + ",";  
        }    
        jsonList = jsonList + "[";  
        jsonList = jsonList + "{";  
        ......  
        jsonList = jsonList + "}";   
        jsonList = jsonList + "]";  
        **var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));  
        $(newDiv).text();  
        $(newDiv).dialog({modal: true, width:850, height:500, title:"JSON for Demo Story"}).dialog("open");**  
        *var obj=document.createElement('textarea');  
        obj.setAttribute("style","padding-left:100");  
        obj.value=jsonList;  
        document.body.appendChild(obj);*   
        storyLst = jsonList;  
        });  
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can append any element in the div you use as the dialog content.

```
var newDiv =  $("<div />"); 
var textArea = $('<textarea style="padding-left:100px" />'); 
textArea.text(jsonList);
newDiv.append(textArea);
newDiv.dialog({modal: true, width:850, height:500, title:"JSON for Demo Story"});
```

See jQuery documentation for [insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) for more functions.

Comment: You mean no need of  "_var obj=document.createElement('textarea');  
        obj.setAttribute("style","padding-left:100");  
        obj.value=jsonList;  
        document.body.appendChild(obj);_" right?

Comment: No need for that. The same can be written as `var obj = $('<textarea style="padding-left:100;" />').text(jsonList); $('body').append(obj);`

Answer (score 0):

some javascript

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    ...............................
});
```

and then some html(you basically have a div with a form inside)

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="<?php echo $this->translate('rifiuta ordine titolo') ?>">
    <form action="/<?=$controller?>/rifiuta/" method="post" name="rifiuta_form">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="motivo"><?php echo $this->translate('note_interne')?></label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <textarea name="motivo" id="motivo" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" rows="25" cols="50" style="height:100%; width: 100%"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="ordine_id" value="" />
        <input type="submit" id ="submit_button" style="display:none" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

this works as i use it in on a website...

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: i would down vote your comment if i could, instead of killing himself trying to create with jQuery a div and and textarea and stuff, you write plain html code and then use $('#div_id').dialog ..., on close you hide the div, on open you show it

Comment: That's a lot better! Please include the rationale to the answer as it.